# Hadoop setup - Java trying to access window server

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

When I launch `start-dfs.sh` in Hadoop 2.2.0 on Mac OS X, buried in the error messages, I have this:

```
2014-02-24 14:48:23,448 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1833)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1730)
    ...
```

I've dealt with this error before - it happens when Java is trying to access the window server (even though it's a command line program). For security reasons, this isn't allowed without a graphical login. This of course means that if you're running a headless server, you have to physically log in before your daemons run.

Now, without going into a rant about how STUPID Java and/or the developers are for doing this (it seems to be a trend; the only other Java server component I use does the same thing), I found the option:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

which looks like a possible solution. But not only do I have no idea where to pass the option to Hadoop, but I tried it on the other software, and it still gives the error.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried it, and it turns out there's two things going on. The option DOES in fact work... for Hadoop. But here's where it gets weird:

1. Hadoop won't append to a log file... if one exists, it leaves it and silently fails to write any logs. So I was looking at old log files.
2. The other software still doesn't work, but they said they're aware of the bug and they're fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using:

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk -Djava.awt.headless=true"

in my bashrc